# Payout Status Remains "Processing" in Test Mode & does not change to processed in razorpay

Tags: razorpay

I've been integrating Razorpay's payouts API (https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payouts) into our system and conducting tests in the test environment. After initiating a payout successfully, I've noticed that the payout status is consistently marked as "Processing" and does not change to "Processed."

The request is successful, and the payout is created with a status of "Processing."
However, even after waiting, the status does not update to "Processed."
My questions are:

Is it expected behavior in the test environment for the payout status to remain "Processing" without changing to "Processed"?

Are there any steps I can take to simulate the status change to "Processed" for testing purposes?

Thank you for your assistance.